The average number of unsuccessful atempts
There is a broken coffee machine in the lobby of the university. Due to a breakdown, the machine gives out coffee with a probability of $0.99$ after each payment. It is known that every student uses a coffee machine exactly until it happens that the machine does not give them coffee twice in a row, despite the payment made. On average, how many unsuccessful purchases do students make in the coffee machine before they stop using it?
All I've been able to figure out so far is that it might have something to do with geometrical distribution. So the probability of the coffee machine failing twice in a row is $p = 0.01\cdot 0.01 = 0.0001$. If we call the machine failing twice in a row a "success" and $N$ is the number of tries (total), then we can say that the probability that $N = k$ for $k = 1, 2, 3,\dots$ equals $(1 - p)^{n-1}\cdot p$. Then the average $N$ is like $\frac{1}{p}$. But I have no idea how to move forward from here, especially considering the fact that I have to calculate the average number of unsuccessfull purchases.

I suggest:  work recursively.  There are two active states:  the one in which the prior result was coffee and the one in which it was a fail (that's also the Start state).  Just keep track of which state you are in and consider the first couple of trials.

Note:  I mis-wrote in my prior comment.  The Start state is the same as the first one I mentioned (the one in which the prior result was a success).

Are you familiar with the Negative Binomial Distribution?

Wait, is this a trick question?! You ask about "how many unsuccessful purchases do students make in the coffee machine before they stop using it?" right after telling us that they stop using the machine after the second unsuccessful purchase. Do you perhaps intend to ask how many purchases (including the usual successful purchases)?

There will be two unsuccessful purchases / student. (We ignore the fact that a student has a finite amount of time in his life around that broken coffee machine.)

@SammyBlack - they stop with two unsuccessful purchases in a row. I.e., each time  they have an unsuccessful purchase followed by a successful one, they will not stop with the next unsuccessful purchase.

There is a puzzle, sometimes called "feminist rule" in which a government intent on increasing the ratio of women to men sterilizes women after they give birth to a boy so they can never have more than one. The question is what effect this would have on ratio of women to men. The solution is to realize that 50% of first children are boys, 50% of second children are boys, etc. so there is no impact gender ratio, just on the number of fertile women. I think a similar thought process may be useful in this problem.
